# Where might I buy/stream "Cyber City Oedo 808"?

Tags: cyber-city-oedo-808

[*Cyber City Oedo 808*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0220218/) happens to be a favourite of mine and I was wondering where I might be able to buy such titles, or what online services might host them for streaming?

The last time I tried was some shifty guy (or girl) selling what looked like a real DVD published but turned out to be terrible copied DVDs on Amazon a long time ago.

Comment: Good question. I enjoyed this show a decent amount back when I was younger and it's been out of print for a long time and is hard to find. For what it's worth I think [this](https://www.amazon.com/Cyber-City-Collection-Hiroya-Ishimaru/dp/B0007939U2/) is the real DVD set; the publisher listed is US Manga Corps, which was the real publisher, whereas the other set I found is published by "DVD, LTD.", which sounds like a front for some guy in his basement burning discs from a VHS recording.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't seen that in ages! Because it's a little older you'll probably have a hard time finding a place to buy or stream it these days. In the US it is indeed distributed by US Manga Corps. However, their parent, Central Park Media, filed for bankruptcy in 2009. Some of their licenses were sold off to other distributors, but this one has expired and has not been picked up again so far as I can find.

I don't think I have my DVD any more to give you a product number but an eBay search might net you someone looking to offload their copy. Of course, be careful where you buy from as with anything on eBay. The usual places I would go to buy (Right Stuf, CDJapan) did not have it.

Comment: Streaming unlicensed anime (excluding the relatively tiny amount of public domain content) is still illegal in most of the world, and in any event the sites that do it tend to be fairly shady. As such we have a blanket ban on linking them on this site. I edited out that part of your answer. The rest of your answer is fine though.

Comment: What sources did you use to check that?  I've never been able to track down things like that.